# Crank Nicolson Method on Wave Function Python

Tags: python, matrix, numerical-methods

I am trying to propagate a gaussian wave packet using the crank nicolson method in imaginary time (multiply the time step by the unit imaginary).  The code that I have written in attempt to achieve this is shown here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #this allows you to plot, and changes the name to plt
import numpy as np #this allows you to do math, and changes the name to np
import math
import scipy.linalg as la

def V(x):
#    k = 1
#    v = k*x**4
    v = 0.25*(x-3)**2+0.15*(x-3)**4
    return v

def Psi(x):
    psi = np.exp(-2*(x-3)**2)
    return psi

#Function for computing integral using trapezoid method 
def TrapInt(y, h):
    trap = [(float(y[ii]) + float(y[ii+1])) for ii in range(0, len(y)-1)]
    return float(h)/2*sum(trap)    

N = 1000
L = 3;
h = 0.01
x = np.arange(0,6,h);
t = np.linspace(0,L,300);
t = 1j*t;
dt = t[1] - t[0]
dx = x[1] - x[0]

A = 1j*dt/(2*dx**2)

pot = V(x)

Q = np.zeros([len(x),len(x)],dtype = complex)
P = np.zeros([len(x),len(x)],dtype = complex)

wave = np.zeros([len(x),len(t)],dtype = complex)
wave[:,0] = Psi(x)

B = (1- 2*A - 1j*dt*pot)

for ii in range(0,len(x)-1):
    Q[ii][ii] = -(B[ii])
    P[ii][ii] = (B[ii])
    Q[ii][ii+1] = (2-A)
    P[ii][ii+1] = A
    if ii >= 1:
        Q[ii][ii-1] = -A
        P[ii][ii-1] = A
plt.plot(wave[:,0])
for ii in range(0,len(t)-1):
    one = np.matmul(P,wave[:,ii])
    wave[:,ii+1] = np.matmul(la.inv(Q),one)
```

I can't seem to find any mathematical errors in my implementation of the crank nicolson method; however, whenever I try to run this it gives an error saying that Q is singular (has no inverse).  I'm not sure why this is occurring.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never assign to `Q[-1]`.  Zero rows have been known to produce singular matrices in some cases.

Also, don’t repeatedly invert the matrix.  Probably don’t invert it at all, but rather store some decomposition of it to allow efficient calculation of *Q*<sup>-1</sup>*x*.